# How does the scope of using classes in Java work?

Tags: java, android

I am not really sure how to word this question, so I did the best I could in that aspect. So I am having a problem with creating a `DatePicker` in my Activity. This is the code that is giving me an error:

**EditEventActivity.java**

```
DateDialogFragment frag = DateDialogFragment.newInstance(this, new 
DateDialogFragmentListener() {

            @Override
            public void updateChangeDate(int year, int month, int day) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }, sYear, sMonth, sDay);
```

---

The `newInstance()` method I have there is whats giving me the error. The error is this:

> ```
> The method newInstance(Context, AddEventActivity.DateDialogFragmentListener, int, int,
> int) in the type DateDialogFragment is not applicable for the arguments 
> (EditEventActivity, new EditEventActivity.DateDialogFragmentListener(){}, int, int, 
> int)
> ```

---

Now the `DateDialogFragment` is located in its own file. I don't think I need to post that. It is what it is. But my interface is in `AddEventActivity.java`. Now this is what I am confused about. My static method, `newInstance()` from DateDialogFragment takes `DateDialogFragmentListener`not `AddEventActivity.DateDialogFragmentListener`. So I assume thats what the problem is. But then again, I am not sure, which is what I need help understanding. Thanks you in advance.

Actually. I also figue I might as well include the `newInstance()` method:

**DateDialogFragment.java**

```
public static DateDialogFragment newInstance(Context context, DateDialogFragmentListener 
listener, int year, int month, int day) {
    DateDialogFragment dialog = new DateDialogFragment();
    mContext = context;
    mListener = listener;
    mYear = year;
    mMonth = month;
    mDay = day;
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", "Set Date");
    dialog.setArguments(args);
    return dialog;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass too many arguments to the `newInstance(...)` method. Only pass `sYear`, `sMonth` and `sDay` once rather than twice.

**Edit**
You're having here two classes with the same simple name but they're different classes and therefore different types. Just pass an instance of the right class.

```
DateDialogFragment frag = DateDialogFragment.newInstance(
    this, 
    new AddEventActivity.DateDialogFragmentListener() {

        @Override
        public void updateChangeDate(int year, int month, int day) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }, sYear, sMonth, sDay);
```

.. or correct the signature of your `newInstance()` method if you need to pass a `EditEventActivity.DateDialogFragmentListener`.

Comment: What is your Exception now? The given Exception is still the one showing exactly this case where you pass too many arguments.

Comment: Just edited it. Same thing minus the three extra ints. Sorry about that, it automatically added it and I must not have noticed.

Comment: I thought about doing it. But I am reusing the `DateDialogFragment` class. So changing the type there wouldn't work. But the first part you said does make sense. But I am confused as to how to pass the an instance of the right class? The `DateDialogFragment` class already expects a `DateDialogFragmentListener`, without any extra class types, meaning I don't understand why its giving me the error.

Comment: We cannot see which `DateDialogFragmentListener` is used when we look at your method but the exception tells us that `AddEventActivity.DateDialogFragmentListener` is used in `DateDialogFragment`. Check the imports in that class or the classes in the same package.

Comment: Actually I think you are right. I did import it, but because I have the inner interface inside of the `AddEventActivity`. I will move the interface to see if that fixes the problem. I appreciate the help and time you just gave me!

Comment: Np, but moving any interface won't help. You've to realize that you've two classes named `DateDialogFragmentListener` which seem not be related to each other in any kind except having the same name. Even when you just write `DateDialogFragmentListener` in your `newInstance` method it is still one of these classes and only compatible to that one and not the other. You can use an interface implemented by both `DateDialogFragmentListener` classes and use that in your `newInstance` method. Then you can have one method that can take any instance of a class implementing that interface.

Comment: Yea good point! I actually just moved the interface to its own file. It seemed to do the trick. I understand now. Again, I really appreciate it. I was so confused as to why this was happening. I was trying to avoid putting the interface in its own file cuz its like 3 lines, but that way and your advice on implementing it also work!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `EditEventActivity.DateDialogFragmentListener` extends `AddEventActivity.DateDialogFragmentListener`, your `newInstance` method takes 3 `int`s after the listener and you are passing 6 `int`s - you probably meant:

```
DateDialogFragment frag = DateDialogFragment.newInstance(this, new DateDialogFragmentListener() {

        @Override
        public void updateChangeDate(int year, int month, int day) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }, sYear, sMonth, sDay); //removed the last 3 arguments
```

**EDIT**
Following your edit, back to my first comment: does `EditEventActivity.DateDialogFragmentListener` extend `AddEventActivity.DateDialogFragmentListener`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Just fixed it. That shouldn't have been there. It was added automatically when I pressed entered and it fille d in itself. But the error is the same minus the three extra erroneous `ints`

Comment: No it does not. It is just an inner class interface.

Comment: well, your method expects an `AddEventActivity.DateDialogFragmentListener` so if you pass in an unrelated object it won't be happy!

Comment: Haha, I know! But as you can see above in my `newInstance` method, it does expect what I am saying! Thats whats confusing me. I dont really get why thats happening. And as you can see from me sending it from `EditEventActivity`, its also the right type

Comment: You need to check your imports and make sure all the objects are of the same class or at least compatible.